# How to insert into database using AJAX, PHP and CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Please tell me how to use AJAX with CodeIgniter. I wrote the view like this but I am not sure how to send data to model with the controller.

My view is:

```
<html>
<head> 

<script>
    function insert(fname,lname,age)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_db_php.php?fname=fname&lname=lname&age=age",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form> 
    <table>
        <tr><td>First Name : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="fname"/> </td> </tr>  
        <tr><td>Last Name : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="lname"/> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td>City : </td><td> <input type="text" fname="age"/> </td> </tr>

        <input type="button" onclick="insert(fname,lname,age)">
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with writing the controller and model for this case.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do it using `GET`, thats for sure. use `POST` instead and look at [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) and [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the idea:

Better use `post` for submitting forms using ajax:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","user_ajax",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&city="+city);
```

**Model**

```
class user extends CI_Model{
    function insert(){
        $data = array(
                    "fname" => $this->input->post('fname'),
                    "lname" => $this->input->post('lname'),
                    "city" => $this->input->post('city')
                );
        return $this->db->insert("TABLE_NAME",$data);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class user_ajax extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model("user");
        if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
            $ths->user->insert();
        }
    }
}
```